# Как проверить, содержится ли в сообщении упоминание с @?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

код:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user:
        print(Fore.YELLOW+'['+str(message.channel)+'] '+Fore.MAGENTA+str(message.author.name)+Fore.WHITE+
              ": "+Fore.MAGENTA+str(message.content)+Fore.RESET)
        stmc = str(message.content)
        await client.process_commands(message)
    else:
        pass
```

Это что-то типа логов в реальном времени в консоли. Нужно добавлять к каждому упоминанию в сообщении ник упомянотого пользователя. Ведь так видно только что-то типо

> <@!718082902696525995>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions), модель `Message` имеет лист `mentions`, который содержит упомянутых пользователей `Member`. У нее в свою очередь есть, например, `nick` пользователя.

Отсюда узнать наличие упоминаний можно по длине листа

```
if len(message.mentions) > 0:
    nicks = [member.nick for member in message.mentions]
    print(nicks)
```